# ipfs.cat(cid) in node js gives error "Error: Invalid version, must be a number equal to 1 or 0 at Function.validateCID"

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js, ipfs, js-ipfs

I am using the ipfs-http-client module.

This is my script

```
async function main() {

const ipfs_client = require('ipfs-http-client');
const client = ipfs_client({recursive: false});


async function addFile(file_data) {
    const cid = function (data) {

        return client.add(data).then(cid =>{return cid;}).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)})
    }
    const real_cid = cid(file_data).then(result=>{return result}).catch(err=>{console.log(err)});
    return real_cid;
}

const sendFileToNet = async (file) => {
    return await addFile(file);
}
async function getFile(cid){

//error occurs here
    for await (const chunk of client.cat(cid)) {
        console.info(chunk)
    }
    return content;
}

const getFileFromNet = async()=>{
    return await getFile();
}
getFileFromNet("QmU77sHBUuCT12324e9Re59bNHekpKg1PdCpiVAj3MFLiH").then(r => console.log(r));
module.exports = {sendFileToNet, getFileFromNet

};

}

main();
```

> (node:22889) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid version, must be a number equal to 1 or 0
> at Function.validateCID (/home/chipego/Documents/MedChain/node_modules/ipfs-http-client/node_modules/cids/src/index.js:346:13)
> at new CID (/home/chipego/Documents/MedChain/node_modules/ipfs-http-client/node_modules/cids/src/index.js:174:9)
> at Object.cat (/home/chipego/Documents/MedChain/node_modules/ipfs-http-client/src/cat.js:16:48)
> at cat.next ()
> at getFile (/home/chipego/Documents/MedChain/logic/ipfs_submit_controller.js:23:26)
> at getFileFromNet (/home/chipego/Documents/MedChain/logic/ipfs_submit_controller.js:30:22)
> at main (/home/chipego/Documents/MedChain/logic/ipfs_submit_controller.js:32:5)
> at Object. (/home/chipego/Documents/MedChain/logic/ipfs_submit_controller.js:39:1)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:22889) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
> (node:22889) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getFile` function takes an argument.  You are invoking it in `getFileFromNet` but not passing the argument in.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess it's just lack of sleep. Senior year project.

Comment: Now I get a Promise {<Pending>} though I handled the promise according to protocal